# Make Asterisk to serve another subnet

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, subnet, asterisk, udp

I have server with **Linux Ubuntu 12.04**. It has two subnets - **192.168.0.1(eth0)** and **192.168.1.1 (eth1)**.

There is an **Asterisk server** (IP PBX) connected to first subnet, lets say it has IP address **192.168.0.28**.

I would need SIP **clients from 192.168.1.x** subnet be able to connect to that Astersik server.

My idea is to make all **SIP clients to connect to** the gateway server (the one that is in both subnets, i.e. the one at **192.168.1.1** of their subnet) and make it to **port forward all UDP 5060** connections to **192.168.0.28** (the IP BPX).

Here is my idea:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -d 192.168.0.28 -p udp --dport 5060 -m state \
    --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p udp --dport 5060 -j DNAT \
    --to-destination 192.168.0.28
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 5060 -d 192.168.0.28 \
    -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

But the SIP clients (softphones) from 192.168.1.x can't register. I have tried to port forward http port just to test it:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -d 192.168.0.28 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state \
    --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT \
    --to-destination 192.168.0.28:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -d 192.168.0.28 \
    -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

and that works fine, but with the first one with UDP forwarding I can't get clients to register at Asterisk server.

**UPD:**

As suggested in [commnets](https://serverfault.com/questions/690957/make-asterisk-to-serve-another-subnet/690960?noredirect=1#comment852011_690960) I would need to use `route` instead of `iptables` so I guess the command would be something like this:

```
route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.28 dev eth0
```

But that didn't really worked. Plus I don't want to expose the whole IP PBX host to the 192.168.1.x network, only 5060 port for the SIP Clients (softphones).

Comment: Can't you just make Asterisk listen on the two interfaces ?

Comment: @André Asterisk has only one internal interface on 192.168.0.28 address. The clients are in 192.168.1.x subnet. There is a Ubuntu Server at 192.168.0.1/192.168.1.1 between them.

Comment: @André But if nothing will work I will have to install Asterisk on the Ubuntu server so it is avaliable from both subnets. But it will be additional load on the server while I have a separate IP BPX hardware running in the first subnet for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why to use NAT? In this scenario, you can directly router between the two LANs, without port forwarding at all.

Anyway, if you *really* want to use NAT, port 5060 should be sufficient **if** your clients are standard SIP ones. If they are mixed/custom protocol clients (eg: Cisco H323 and/or SCTP/SCCP implementation) you will need to open additional port ranges.

**EDIT:** the route you added is wrong. Let me illustrate your network setup:

```
    LAN 192.168.0.x/24              LAN 192.168.1.x/24
     ----------------                ----------------
     |  |  |  |  |  |                |  |  |  |  |  |
     |              |                |              |
     |              |                |              |
    PBX             |  UBUNTU SERVER |          SIP CLIENT
192.168.0.28   192.168.0.1      192.168.1.1  eg: 192.168.1.10
                    |                |
                    |________________|
```

As by your description, the Ubuntu server is a multihomed host - it has one interface on LAN 192.168.0.x and another interface on LAN 192.168.1.x. In order to route between the networks, you need to announce *to the clients* that the Ubuntu machine serves as a *gateway* for the other LAN. Assuming all involved machines are Linux clients, you need:

- on each 192.168.0.x machine you issue `route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 gw 192.168.0.1`
- on each 192.168.1.x machine you issue `route add -net 192.168.0.x/24 gw 192.168.1.1`
- on the Ubuntu server, you can setup a firewall rules to only forward/route packet for 192.168.0.28 issuing `iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.0.28 -j ACCEPT` and `iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.28 -j ACCEPT`

Please note that the steps outlined above have only illustration purpose and *are not* best practices: for example, rather than issuing a specific routing command inside each clients, you can (and should) insert the right routes on the LAN's respective gateways.

However, this is networking at very basic level - if you are asking that, you **really** need to document yourself on what routing/NAT are and how to effectively use them.

Comment: Are you sure I can access them directly? For example, If I ping 192.168.0.28 from 192.168.1.x subnet I get no answer. Same with telnet 192.168.0.28:5060 from 192.168.1.x

Comment: plus I don't want to open the whole 192.168.0.x subnet, only the PBX server.

Comment: As it seems that you don't know what routing is and how to configure it, I strongly suggest you to first read [something as that](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understand-the-basics-of-linux-routing/). Anyway, combining routing and firewalling (FORWARD chain) you can accomplish what you want in a cleaner way than using NAT/port forwarding.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer with the illustration! That worked now! I have added the route at IP PBX only not on each 192.168.0.x machines and that was enough. Now all SIP clients can connect from 192.168.1.x. But the last question is how I forward UDP 5060 only as they also see the web interface of asterik etc. which is not secure.

Comment: Sure this is possible. You had to remove the iptables forward rules above and insert some new, more restrictive rules. In practice, you must issue the following commands: `iptables -D FORWARD -d 192.168.0.28 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -s 192.168.0.28 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.0.28 -p udp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.28 -p udp --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP`